# DropzoneJS: add CSV to acceptedFile's list

Tags: csv, dropzone.js

I am using **[ngx-dropzone-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-dropzone-wrapper)** Angular 2 wrapper for fileupload. Its working as expected if `acceptedFiles: 'image/*'` I changed acceptedFiles to `'csv/*'`, `'.csv/*'`, `'.csv'` and `'csv'` trying to make it work for CSV files but it is not working.

How do I change the config to accept CSV files?

**config:**

```
import { DropzoneModule } from 'ngx-dropzone-wrapper';
import { DropzoneConfigInterface } from 'ngx-dropzone-wrapper';

const DROPZONE_CONFIG: DropzoneConfigInterface = {
  server: AppSettings.backendServiceUrl + 'upload_endpoint',
  maxFilesize: 50,
  acceptedFiles: 'csv'
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin uses *mime type* `text/csv` instead of file extensions i.e: .csv

Comment: Hey, there is an issue as some csv file which edited in Windows OS, will save as application/vnd.ms-excel